# Can't figure out where the letter g is coming from

Tags: wordpress

On our WP website https://www.vivantepg.net/, there is a "g" at the top of the page.  I have disabled all plugins, reinstalled WordPress 6.02, switched to the twenty-twenty (and twenty-twentytwo) themes, deleted my child theme and the g still shows. I have also checked htaccess, wp-settings and wp-config. I can not figure out where the **g** is coming from!

I am having other issues that may be related:
-- I can't update the Ultimate Member database Ultimate Member updated to 2.5 and the database is at 2.3, but the update attempt stalls out.
-- If I try to add a plugin, the search results page never loads

Answer (score 1):

@Selcuk, Thanks for the suggestions; however that code was not found in the header.

What I wound up doing was deleting my themes, except twent-twentytwo downloading and unzipping a new copy of WordPress. I replaced every WordPress file except the config and settings files with new ones. The problem still persisted.

I used the sample config and copied my database and salts values into it and replaced the live config with the sample.  The g went away. So it was somewhere in the config files.  I'm more concerned with how it got there!

Now, I wonder what else is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website's source code and realised, it is just a HTML coding problem that has been added by mistake. You need to delete that "g" manually from your `Header.php` file which you can access by FTP or File Manager plugin. It is the first thing you will see, just delete and save. But before doing that take a back-up of the file in case if you delete anything else whole website can crush. If you can't find it in `Header.php` then look for `Default.php` file. Let me know if you have any questions.

[image: html structure of your page]